# difference between result from useQuery hook (apolloClient) and getStaticProps (NextJS)

Tags: express, graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I'm new to NextJS and GraphQL, and i'm building an app using MERN stack with (NextJS and GraphQL).
And i just need a clarification about whether i use the data returned from the query in `getStaticProps(nextJS)` or the data returned from `useQuery` hook (apollo/Client)

for example: i have a component which fetches a data depends on ID its name is [id].tsx,
and i know that in nextJS we use `getStaticProps` to fetch data before the component is generated,
like so in my component

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {

  let oneUserQuery = await client.query({
    query: ONE_USER_QUERY,
    variables: { id: params.id }
  });

  let user = oneUserQuery.data.userInfo;

  return {
    props: {
      user   //we fetched the userInfo and we have access to it in [id].tsx component props
    }
  };
};
```

and in the component itself we can use useQuery hook provided by apollo/client to fetch  data with the same graphQL query like so

```
export default function User(props) {
//here we have access to user in the props and we can render using it

  const route = useRouter();

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ONE_USER_QUERY, {
    variables: { id: route.query.id }
  });

  if (error) return <div>Error loading one user.</div>;
  if (loading) return <div>Loading.....</div>;

  const { userInfo } = data;

  return (
    <Layout>
      {userInfo.id}       // also could be {props.user.id)
      <br />
      {userInfo.name}     // also could be {props.user.name)
      <br />
      {userInfo.email}    // also could be {props.user.email)
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

both works fine and i can access the userInfo and loading state from both returned value, but which approach is the right one and what is the difference between them?

Comment: I have the same question, did you figure it out?

Comment: @MarkSteggles Not really, i just used both in different components cause i don't know the difference, if you figured it out i wish you add your answer here, and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 3):

`getStaticProps` updates query results only when `revalidate` option is set. `useQuery` will automatically update when apollo cache changes. So it is generally better to use `useQuery`. If you need `revalidate` like behaviour than you can set `polling` option in `useQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article with diagrams very useful to first understand the differences between 3 types of Rendering when using Apollo Client with Nextjs (https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/next-js/next-js-getting-started/)

**1. Static Rendering**

**2. Client-side Rendering**

**3. Server-side Rendering**

Then, if considering **Static Rendering**,  learning about Nextjs pros and cons when using Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR) and  “On-Demand” ISR (Introduced in Next.js 12.2, June 29th 2022) :

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2021/03/08/incremental-static-regeneration-its-benefits-and-its-flaws/

https://kontent.ai/blog/leveraging-next-js-on-demand-isr/

Good insights when deciding to use **Static Rendering / Server-Side Rendering**
(via `client.query` in `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`) or **Apollo Client-Side Rendering** via `useQuery`

Additional Note:
When using Static Rendering, you may need to disable Apollo Client Side Caching (`fetchPolicy: "no-cache"`) as per answer here: [How does the revalidate process in Incremental Static Regeneration work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077408/how-does-the-revalidate-process-in-incremental-static-regeneration-work/73610328#73610328)