# revalidate in getStaticProps seem doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I try to revalidate data using getStaticProps in Next js every 3 seconds, but it seems doesn't work as expected, data doesn't revalidate after 3 seconds.

This is my code:

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  console.log("Hello")
  let error = false 
  let data = []
  try{
    const response = await axios.get('https://some-service/events')
    for(const key in response.data){
      const resData = response.data[key]
      data.push({id: key, ...resData})
    }
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
    error = true
  }finally{  
    return {
      props: {
        data,
        error
      },
      revalidate: 3
    }
  }
}
```

I am running localhost using

> npm run build && npm run start

also, try using:

> npm run dev

This is my component code:

```
function HomePage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <EventList items={props.data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the data not revalidate at all, or takes longer than 3 seconds?

Comment: data do not revalidate at all, even after 5 minutes of wait.

Comment: Next.js will only regenerate the page when a new request come in, after the revalidate period has passed - it doesn't automatically revalidate.

Comment: So it explains why we need to trigger the refresh button a second time, to get new data?
Thank you this is clear now. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration

So basically we need a library like React-SWR to perform automatic data?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And yes, you can use a library like [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation) for auto revalidation.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How does the revalidate process in Incremental Static Regeneration work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077408/incremental-static-regeneration-revalidate-process)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. Thanks for validating me with resources.