# View not updating content in deployed app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, heroku-postgres, vercel

I have a react nextjs app deployed to Vercel. It uses Prisma to connect to a heroku postgresql db.

When I create a new record in the db it updates the page... on localhost. When I deploy the app to Vercel I have to refresh the screen twice before the new data is presented.

What could be the cause of this?

An FYI: localhost and the deployed app use the same heroku hosted db.

The view:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const feed = await prisma.post.findMany({
    include: {
      author: {
        select: {
          name: true,
        },
      },
    },
  })

  return {
    props: { feed },
    revalidate: 10,
  }
}

type Props = {
  feed: PostProps[]
}

const Blog: React.FC<Props> = ({ feed = [] }) => {
  return (
    <main>
      {feed.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.id} className="post">
          <Post post={post} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </main>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

This is the function that updates the data and redirects to the page that is meant to show the new data

```
async function publishPost(id: number): Promise<void> {
  await fetch(`/api/publish/${id}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
  })
  await Router.push('/')
}
```

Comment: That's how Incremental Static Regeneration works, the first request after the `revalidate` period has passed will trigger the page's regeneration but will get served the old version - see [How does the revalidate process in Incremental Static Regeneration work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077408/how-does-the-revalidate-process-in-incremental-static-regeneration-work). This doesn't apply to dev mode, because [`getStaticProps` runs on every request](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development) to the page in that case.