# How Next.js ISR revalidate big number of pages?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to understand the strategy of page revalidation in Next.js. Let's assume that I have a 500000 pages (some sort of e-commerce project; goods pages). I have a top 1000 pages, which generated staticaly at build time (getStaticPaths for 1000 pages), and other pages generated on request (fallback: 'blocking' in getStaticProps) and cached. I want to revalidate this pages, for example, every 60 seconds (revalidate: 60 in getStaticProps). Next.js's regeneration takes place on the server one page at a time. Every page regenerates at least for 20-30 ms (if we lucky). That means that in my case cycle of all page regeneration takes at least 500000 * 20 / 1000 = 10000 seconds = 2.77 hours. That means, that there is a case in which goods seller must wait more than 2 hours until the description of his goods will refreshed if his page not so lucky to be in the start of regeneration queue at description change moment.
How Next.js handles this situations? Will it place requested pages to the start of regeneration queue for faster regeneration?

Comment: ISR revalidation doesn't happen automatically, it occurs when a request is made to the page after the revalidation time has passed. See [How does the revalidate process in Incremental Static Regeneration work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077408/how-does-the-revalidate-process-in-incremental-static-regeneration-work). The scenario you describe would only happen if you'd get a request for each of the 500000 pages at the same time. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks. I really misunderstood revalidation process. You helped me a lot.